# white screen after using npm run build react app

Tags: reactjs, npm, build

After using

```sh
npm run build
```

to build developed application for deployment it shows white screen when opening

> build/index.html

while I'm setting homepage: "." in package.json.

Console Errors Screen shots
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86tNC.png)

Comment: Please mention the error shown in the console.

Comment: I have mentioned the screen shot of the errors in the question I have asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to run the project whit a npm package called serve

```sh
serve -s build
```

this worked for me instead of opening the file from /build/index.html directly